# Checking Checkboxes In Custom Listview From Parse.com

Tags: java, android, android-listview, parse-platform, android-checkbox

i'm facing a problem of logic.

I'm getting data from Parse.com and i need to mark checkboxes as checked if the current user is liking a card.

Everything works fine but i have to scroll down and up to change the status of the checkboxes

here is my code

```js
public class CardsFragment extends  ListFragment {

    public static final String TAG = CardsFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    protected List<ParseObject> mCards;
    protected ParseRelation<ParseObject> mUserCategoriesRelation;
    protected ParseRelation<ParseObject> mCardsLikeRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cards, container,
                false);


        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        final List<CardModel> list = new ArrayList<CardModel>();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        mCardsLikeRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation("cardLikesRelation");
        mUserCategoriesRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_CATEGORIES_RELATION);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseConstants.CLASS_CARD);
        query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_DELETED, false);
        query.orderByDescending(ParseConstants.KEY_CREATED_AT);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> cards, ParseException e) {

                getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                if (e == null) {
                    mCards = cards;

                    for (final ParseObject card : mCards) {

                        list.add(get(card.getString("title"), card.getString("content"), card.getString("background"), card.getBoolean("background_image"),card.getInt("likes")));

                    }


                    if (getListView().getAdapter() == null) {
                        ArrayAdapter<CardModel> adapter = new CardAdapter(getListView().getContext(),
                                list);
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    } else {
                        //refill the adapter
                        ((CardAdapter) getListView().getAdapter()).refill(list);

                    }

                    int i = 0;
                    for (final ParseObject card : mCards) {
                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> likesQuery = mCardsLikeRelation.getQuery();
                        likesQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", card.getObjectId());

                        final int finalI = i;
                        likesQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(List<ParseObject> likes, ParseException e) {

                                if (e == null) {
                                    //list returned - look for a match
                                    Log.e(TAG, "likes" + likes.size());

                                    if (likes.size() == 1) {
                                        //liked
                                       list.get(finalI).setSelected(true);


                                    } 

                                } else {

                                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                                }

                            }

                        });
                        i++;
                    }

                } else {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getListView().getContext());
                    builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                            .setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }


            }

        });

    }


    private CardModel get(String title, String content, String background, boolean background_image, int likes) {
        return new CardModel(title, content, background, background_image, likes);
    }

}
```

Comment: If i'm understanding your code correctly, you are setting whether its checked after you populate your adapter and attach it to the listview, which is why you have to scroll, because it has to get a new view in order for it to be updated.

Comment: If do list.get(0).setSelected(true); it work fine, no matter how many i add!

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

In the second query fetching likes by user i used

```js
likesQuery.find();
```

Instead of

```js
likesQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {});
```